# Linking two tables and looking for association tables

Tags: r, data-analysis

I working in r-studio trying to link two already loaded tables and then look for association rules.

### The set-up:

I have two tables of data:

- "uData" with the fields [user.id, rating, timestamp]
- "uUser" with the fields [user.id, age, gender, occupation]

In uData each user can appear more than once, while in uUser each is listed just once.  I have loaded the data in using r-studios import dataset. I using arules, datasets, graphics, grDecies, lattice, Matrix, methods, stats, and utils packages.

### End goal:

Find the association rules between rating, age and gender

### Q1

I believe I would need to iterate through my uData table and pull in the age and gender for each line from uUser.  I'm unsure how to make the new table or if a new table is necessary to accomplish my end goal.

### Q2

The end goal is to try to find the association rules.  I have been trying to use

> rules <- apriori(***_*_**, parameter = list(supp = .5, conf = .9, target = "**_**"))

After looking over some tutorials I'm getting it to work for dummy data but not the data I have loaded. I am not sure how to have each row labeled a transaction.  I have tried

> transactions = read.transactions(uUser)

but this is met with warnings.  Any help is appreciated.

---

Here is a couple lines of data from uData:

```
user.id rating  timestamp
1       4   878542420
1       3   888732928
4       4   878542699
1       4   875072547
5       3   875636053
```

Here is a couple lines of data from uUser:

```
index   user.id age gender  occupation
1           1   24  M   technician
2           2   53  F   other     
3           3   23  M   writer    
4           4   24  M   technician
5           5   33  F   other
```

Comment: The functions you mention aren't in base - you need to load a package to have access to those.  You should mention which packages you're using and if possible provide some example data.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I have updated the original question with the packages and some example data.  If you want to see more data or the whole data file let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an explicit loop, you can use plyr::join to match the user.id field, then perform your analysis:

```
> library(plyr)
> join(uData, uUser, by='user.id')
  user.id rating timestamp index age gender occupation
1       1      4 878542420     1  24      M technician
2       1      3 888732928     1  24      M technician
3       4      4 878542699     4  24      M technician
4       1      4 875072547     1  24      M technician
5       5      3 875636053     5  33      F      other
```

Comment: That does the trick for Q1 but now I'm struggling with how to find association rules between rating, age and gender. Thanks for your help.